# Simulator Crash when i am using table view in Xcode 5

Tags: c++, ios, xcode5

I want to ask about a crash that is happening when I am using a table view and I don't know how to solve it first i tried to change the debugger form LLDB to GDB but nothing change and now i am using the Xcode 5 but i am still having the same problem 
the problem is:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

and in the console:

```
argc = (int) 1 
argv = (char **) 0xbfffee4c
```

Comment: Too less info, blindly - did you implemented tableview datasource required methods ?

Comment: The simulator crashes or the app running in the simulator?

Comment: please put the clear code ...it always take you to the main class when any error occurs...its generic.. just give the .m file code of your controller where you put the uitableview

Answer (score -2):

if you are using tableView, first you need to implement the datasource and delegate methods of the `UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate` protocols, these are the methods you need to implement

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

       return number_of_rows;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"some text you want to show";
    cell.imageView.image = @"some image";

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // do some action like push next view controller and pass the data  
}
```

check if you have connected datasource and delegates from the storyboard to your file owner.
[image: see image] and do same for delegate

Comment: how you can suggest the answer... without knowing the real problem??